# MSAccess - Conditional GroupBy?

Tags: ms-access

I need to merge pairs of adjacent records in a recordset.  Applying a GroupBy gets me part way to my result, but is over-achieving - it is merging invalid pairs.

My GroupBy key contains 3 Attrs:

1. Dept
2. Area
3. ItemNo

This should suffice to identify the unique PAIRS of rows, but I also may have instances where "ItemNo" = 0 (due to holes/Nulls in my client's data).  There is no other opportunity in the data to uniquely identify the records.  My Problem:  A Dept/Area may have MANY "0" ItemNos.

I tried adding the criteria "ItemNo <> 0", but the result is now MISSING these rows.  I need them, just NOT to be included in the GroupBy.

Data for Illustration:

```
Dept  Area   ItemNo  Desc      Attr1  Attr2  
10    1001   0       Glove A   12     $1.00   
10    1001   0       Suture    3      $10.00
10    1001   0       Glove B   123    $3.456
10    1001   0       Forceps   11     $123.45
10    1001   12345   Glove     11     $110.99     
10    1001   12345   Glove     99     $220.00
10    1001   23456   Catheter  33     $55.12
10    1001   23456   Catheter  66     $99.99
```

In the example above, I do not want to group/sum any of the first 4 rows, but I do want to merge each of the last 2 pairs of rows, (i.e., grab 1st of Desc, Max of Attr1 and Sum of Attr2).

Question: Can I conditionally perform this GroupBy to omit the all rows with ItemNo = 0 from the merge action (Sum, first, max, etc.), but retain the records in the net result?

In my example, I would expect 6 rows in my result vs the 3 rows I am seeing currently.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the Item number actually 0 or Null ? If you used a NZ(ItemNo,0) then all the nulls / 0 values would be able to be grouped ?

Comment: The Nulls in the Client data were intentionally set = 0 to permit upstream queries to function as expected, vs sometimes problematic Nulls.

Comment: Do your records contain a column that can serve as a unique identifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not optimal, but does give the desired result:

Broke the query into 2 parts -

1) GroupBy Query with ItemNo <> 0

2) Select Query with ItemNo = 0

Then, UNION the above 2 results back together.